# How to choose the next point closest to the current position from the curve consisting of points？

Tags: algorithm, math, game-development

[image]
As it shown above, my goal is for the player to start from "S" and choose a point that is closest to the player and is naturally reasonable(i mean i can't walk through the wall),the player always moves along the red line. the red line was defined by a sequence of ordered point.when the player peform jumping action,it may leave serial points behind，so must i choose one point closest to current position to fall ,and lands on the one.

But because the shortest distance between the two points is W, 
it suddenly move through to the other side,this does not take “tunneling effect” problem  into account, which is definitely not what we want.actually what i desire is "N".

Of course, i have used cross-production to determine if the point being chosen is relative to the left-side or right-side of my current location.with points on the right-side of my position has been chosen as candidates,then pick one of them, which is minimum distance compared with others.

any hints on this,look forward to your reply,thank you.

Comment: how do you calculate distance between points?

Comment: here's my workaround. This is very intuitive and uses Intersection-Detection for additional judgment,but it's not concise, not even dealing with extreme situations.so hope for better ways.

Comment: @miradham. Straight line distance between current position and the point being selected. choose one that is minimum distance

Comment: @High Performance Mark.thank you reply.i know what you mean, It was just nothing more than array of points arranged in order(order of insertion), no edge between points,no more info. so i was stumped by these limited info.

Comment: Is the player constrained to moving along the line only? If so, and the line is defined by a sequence of ordered points... you just find your desired point in the list, and if it's to the right of your current position, you move to the next position. This gives the desired result here. But this seems too obvious. Is the player not strictly constrained to moving along the line? Or is the line not strictly defined by a sequence of points?

Comment: @Patrick87 . thank your reply. yes. it moves along red line and the line was strictly defined by a sequence of points.

Comment: @High Performance Mark. No, The player will jump up from the ground, may be a big jump,then the point next to the current point in the sequence is definitely not what we want, so we need to choose a reasonable one.

Comment: Given what you explained, I would use as a distance between two points of the line the sum of distances in the sequence between those points. Does that work?